# HighCharts box-plot: how to make it horizontal

Tags: highcharts

I need to create a box-plot chart with HighCharts 3.0 and to place the box horizontally rather than vertically.  Anybody has any idea how to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see what you have attempted and why it did not work for you.

Answer (score 15):

My comment aside here is how to do it [`inverted`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.inverted)

```
chart: {
    type: 'boxplot',
    inverted: true
},
```